# what is the probability of getting a three , a seven, and an ace?

Tags: probability

Three cards are drawn at random from a full deck. what is the probability of getting a three , a seven, and an ace?

Can someone help me with this question please, thanks!

Comment: How many three-card hands have a $3$, a $7$, and an Ace? The $3$ can be chosen in $4$ ways. For every such choice $\dots$.

Answer (score 1):

To select a three card hand from the $52$ cards in the deck that includes an ace, a three, and a seven, one of the four aces, one of the four threes, and one of the four sevens must be selected.  Hence, the probability that a three card hand contains an ace, a three, and a seven is 
$$P = \frac{\binom{4}{1}^3}{\binom{52}{3}}$$

Comment: But this is not the answer...

Comment: If you evaluate the expression, you will obtain $$\frac{16}{5525} = \frac{2^4}{5^2 \cdot 13 \cdot 17}$$

Comment: 4^3/52*51*50= 8/16575

How did you evaluate it...

Comment: Remember that $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$  Thus, $$\binom{52}{3} = \frac{52!}{3!49!} = \frac{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49!}{3!49!} = \frac{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}$$  Thus, $$\frac{\binom{4}{1}^3}{\binom{52}{3}} = \frac{4^3}{\frac{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}} = 4^3 \cdot \frac{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50} = \frac{16}{13 \cdot 17 \cdot 25} = \frac{16}{5525}$$

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: (since we encourage not just giving the fully solution to simple homework-like problems when)

Drawing a $3$ happens with $p=4/52$

Then drawing a $7$ happens with $p=4/51$

Then drawing an ace happens with $p=4/50$

Next the question is how to combine these probabilities... Are you familiar with the Fundamental Counting Principle?

Finally, you need to correct for the fact that what I've described isn't quite the problem. Rather, it's the answer to a closely related problem.

Comment: but if you multiply them up you get 4^3/52*51*50. The correct answer should be 2^4/(5^2*13*17). I don't know how...

Comment: Well yes, this is a hint, not a fully worked out solution. I'll edit to make it more clear, but there's something else you need to take into account

Comment: Don't ignore hint from @AndreNicholas. What is the ratio of the two answers in your last comment? (As often in probability answerbooks, the form of the answer does not fully reveal the thought process.)

Comment: The ratio is 1:6..

Comment: @Zeus579 Correct! What's the connection between the number 6 and the problem at hand. More precisely, why is $6$ the answer to the question "how much is my calculation wrong by"

Comment: Further hint: $6=3!$

Comment: I just don't get why you multiply it by 3!

Comment: Further hint: what is $n!$ typically used to calculate? And where in this problem might you have $n=3$?

Answer (score 0):

How many "good" cards are possible on the first draw? Three categories of four members - that's 12 of all 52.
Then suppose we hit one. We now need one of the other two categories, and each has 4 members - that's 8 of just 51 - since we already have a card.
Now if we got lucky, our third card must be in the one remaining category with four members - 4 of 50 - we're holding the other two cards of the deck.
This is $(12×8×4)/(52×51×50)=16/(13×17×25)=16/5525$. 
At least, as long as I reduced the fraction without error.

Comment: When you reduce the fraction, you should obtain $$\frac{16}{13 \cdot 17  \cdot 25} = \frac{16}{5525}$$

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: I was working in my head and dropped $4^2$ when factorising. Changed it now. Zeus579, are you referring to the answer or the comments?